# Proving that $k[C]$ is a Dedekind domain for a smooth affine curve $C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, dedekind-domain, affine-varieties

Let $C$ be an affine smooth curve over a field $k$. I want to prove that the coordinate ring $k[C]$ is a Dedekind domain, using the following proposition:

> Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain with fraction field $K$. Let $L$ be a finite separable field extension of $K$ and denote by $B$ the integral closure of $A$ in $L$. Then $B$ is a Dedekind domain.

The following is my attempt of solution. Suppose that we have a finite morphism $f: C\to \mathbb{A}^1_k$, i.e. the pullback $f^*:k[\mathbb{A}^1_k]=k[t]\hookrightarrow k[C]$ is injective and $k[t]\subseteq k[C]$ is an integral extension of rings. Then, since $C$ is a smooth curve, $k[C]$ is integrally closed, so the integral closure of $k[t]$ in $k(C)$ is $k[C]$. Now, if $k(C)/k(t)$ is separable, I can apply the previous proposition with $A=k[t]$.

So, my questions are:

1. Is it true that a finite morphism $f: C\to \mathbb{A}^1_k$ always exists?
2. Is it true that $k(C)/k(t)$ is a separable extension of fields?
3. Do we need to assume that $k$ is algebraically closed?

Thank you.

Edit: Maybe, 1. is a particular case of Noether normalization lemma, right?

Comment: $k = \overline{k}$. I think $t$ is any non-constant regular function $\in k[C]$. Then $k(C)$ is a finite extension of $k(t)$. And $k[C]$ (the regular functions) is finitely generated over $k[t]$ thus it is integral. Integral elements (with monic minimal polynomial) can't have poles. So $k[C]$ is the integral closure of $k[t]$ and it is a Dedekind domain.